# Installation failed for gdb in kali linux

Tags: installation, apt, c++, gdb

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gdb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gdb' has no installation candidate
```

While working with `vscode` when I configured my `launch` and task `json` and hit **`f5`**.It gave me error that MIDebugger path is not specified then went to bin library but could not find `gdb` so I decided to install `gdb` (debugger) on my kali machine got the above error.

**How to resolve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can install anything with the apt, you need to download (update) the package lists from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Update will reach out to the repositories configured in `/etc/apt/source.list` and in files in `/etc/apt/source.list.d` directory.
Make sure the `source.list` file is not empty and the repositories are not commented out with `#`.

It should contain at least one line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

If it is missing, simply edit the file and add it or paste the below command:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that run again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After running update you can search the apt-cache for the `gdb`, and grep the description to limit the output:

```
apt-cache search gdb | grep 'gdb - GNU Debugger'
```

If you will get the output it means you can install it now from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

Comment: I have tried this . Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: And it is still not working?

Comment: Ya still it does not work .

Comment: @Romanik gdb is a debugger for mingw compilers I have this on my window machine I want it on kali so it will debug my c++ file . When I execute `apt-cache search gdb` it show a list out of which only one is useful to me libcc1-0 -GCC cc1 plugin for GDB and I have already installed it to latest version

Comment: Cat you add output of commands: `lsb_release -a`; `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `dig +short http.kali.org`?

Comment: ~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.2
Codename:       kali-rolling

Comment: $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2020.2rc3 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20200508-14:35]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
#deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2020.2rc3 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20200508-14:35]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see thesrc

Comment: dig +short http.kali.org shows the ip address of Apache2 Debian Default Page

Comment: I have upvote for your valuable time hope u will come with some kind of solution {:)

Comment: @Dev Parzival Like I have mentioned in the Answer, execute the command starting with `echo`. It will inject proper online repository into the source.list. After that continue with `update` and `install`.
If you still won't be able to continue with installation, I need actual IP from `dig +short http.kali.org`

Comment: I have already executed command given by u

Comment: @Dev Parziva are you using live CD or is Kali installed on your harddrive?

Comment: I have installed kali on my virtual machine(virtual box by oracle) .

Comment: @Dev Parziva If you have executed `echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list` the file `source.list` would have only the line I have provided you. Try again, make sure you are providing the correct password and verify by `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: it worked I have installed `gdb` successfully thanks for your help now I can resume my work thank  u thanks bro.